# Set boundary for Google Map using Android Maps API v2

Tags: android

Is it possible to put an image overlay Google map and set the boundary for Google Map?
When scroll out of the overlay image, the image bounce back to the position so that user will always see the image and not the Google Map.

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: new to android and have tried out with GroundOverlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : no it's a built in object.

You can however implement a zoom and more detecting touch event in an overlay layout above your map image (I suppose local map or a game?)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. If you don't want google map, just try another map like [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)